# How to multiple data between fragments?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation

Now in my app, I want to pass three string values between two fragments using the navigation component.

So is there any to do this and can I pass custom data type like a **data class**

Comment: ViewModel is recommended way by Google for communicating between two fragments. For more information read [this post](https://androidwave.com/fragment-communication-using-viewmodel/)

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using navigation component you can simply use Safe Args to pass data between fragments. With safe args it is possible to use three `string` parameters or `Custom Parcelable` or `Custom Serializable` parameters.

You can check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data) for more information